# How to assign an autocomplete value to a hidden field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

i have created search using ajax , jquery . There im auto filtering category names from category table and category items from content tables in same auto-filter box .

What i want is if auto-filter select value is category , value should assign to a category_id hidden field and if auto-filter select value is item name ignore the assigning an do the search.

please advice me how to proceed this.

**json**

```
$query="SELECT  b.title,b.id
FROM sltdb_cddir_categories b
WHERE  b.title like '%".$searchc."%' AND b.parent_id BETWEEN 84 AND 107 AND b.level=3
UNION
SELECT  a.title,  a.id
FROM  sltdb_cddir_content a join
      sltdb_cddir_categories b
      on a.categories_id = b.id
WHERE a.title like '%".$searchc."%'AND b.parent_id BETWEEN 84 AND 107 AND b.level=3
 ";


 $db -> setQuery($query);
// Load the results as a list of associated arrays.
$results = $db -> loadAssocList();
 $json=array();
 foreach ($results as $json_result) {
 $json[] = array(
     'value' => $json_result["id"],

    'label' =>  $json_result["title"]
 );
}


 echo json_encode($json);
```

**jquery and form**

```
 jQuery(function(){
              jQuery("#searchc").autocomplete({
                  source:'product.php',
                    delay: 300 ,

                  minLength:1,

                  select: function(event, ui) {
                      jQuery('#categories_id').val(ui.item.value);
                  }

              });

          });
```

Name

```
                <td><p>Location</p>
                    <input type="text" id="addressc" name="address"  /></td>
                     <input type="hidden" id="categories_id" name="categories_id" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#searchc").change(function(){
  if($(this).val()=="category")
  {
    $("#category_id").val($(this).val());
   }
});
```

**Edit**

```
jQuery(function () {
jQuery("#searchc").autocomplete({
    source: 'product.php',
    delay: 300,

    minLength: 1,

    select: function (event, ui) {
      if(ui.item.value=="category")
      {
        jQuery('#categories_id').val("json here");
      }

    }

});

});
```

Comment: so is it ok to add this to my current jquery code ?

Comment: one more thing  that , if its a category i want to get a    value for json array and if its not a category i want to get label , how to proceed this , pls advice

Comment: what is the foramat of your json?

Comment: @user3406921 is that what you want?

Comment: yes but my code doesnt work properly. when i search items also it assign value to hidden field. where i want to stop that  and search item using title and category using id

Comment: check now. I've removed that

Comment: what shoud i put for the "json here" place

Comment: and i also want to if the $searchc filter values is not a category it should not assign a hidden field value . how to proceed this